# Intersection Array of the Johnson Graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I've defined the Johnson Graph as having parameters $n$, and $d$ with $d\leq n/2$. The vertices are the size $d$ subsets of $[n]$ and two vertices are adjacent if and only if the size of their intersection is $d-1$.

I've already shown that two vertices are at distance $j$ if the size of their intersection is $d-j$.

Now I need to show that for its intersection array as a distance regular graph, $b_j=(d-j)(n-d-j)$ and $c_j=j^2$. I'm just at a loss and seem to have some sort of block.

I started by choosing a vertex $z$ is at distance $j$ from a fix vertex $x$, and I need to argue that the number of neighbors to $z$ which are at distance $j+1$ is $(d-j)(n-d-j)$. If we choose such a $y$, it must intersect $z$ at all but one element, and must intersect $x$ at $d-(j+1)$ elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll switch to capital letters $X$ and $Z$ just because I can't bear to write lowercase letters for sets.

To find a neighbor $Y$ of $Z$, remove an element of $Z$, and add an element of $[n] \setminus Z$. The two factors that affect the distance between $X$ and $Y$ are:

- Did we remove an element of $Z \setminus X$ ($j$ "good" choices) or an element of $X \cap Z$ ($d-j$ "bad" choices)?
- Did we add an element of $X \setminus Z$ ($j$ "good" choices) or an element of $[n] \setminus (X \cup Z)$ ($n-d-j$ "bad" choices)?

I've labeled the choices "good" or "bad" according to whether they help $Y$ get closer to $X$. If we make two good choices, then the distance from $X$ to $Y$ will be $j-1$. If we make two bad choices, then the distance from $X$ to $Y$ will be $j+1$. If we make a good choice and a bad choice, then the distance from $X$ to $Y$ will be $j$.

Comment: Thank you so much! And I get uneasy too but tend to flip flop when I’m using sets as vertices of a graph.